# How can I chmod a directory to drwxr-sr-x?

Tags: linux, centos

How can I change a directory's permission to: `drwxr-sr-x` under linux?

Comment: What have you tried?  How would you change a file's permission to: ```-rwxr-sr-x```?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With:

```
chmod u=rwx,g=rx+s,o=rx /path/to/dir
```

Will give you lowercase s instead of uppercase S. The lowercase s bit on the group permission means that the directory is setguid. Any directory created in that directory will belong to the same group as its parents directory instead of the default group of the user that created it.